# Parametric variable in type class

Tags: haskell

I have a parametric variable in a type class which I would like to represent any of the number types (`Float`, `Integer`, `Double` etc).

How I do declare this in the type and instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean the type parameter for the class itself, you can add a constraint to the context of the class definition:

```
class (Num a) => Foo a where
    -- stuff
```

On the other hand, if it's a parameter in a function's type that isn't the class parameter, then you can add a constraint in the usual fashion:

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: (Num b) => a -> b -> b
```

If you want to constrain it to only certain specific types, that's not really possible--type classes are "open", i.e., you can always add instances. The best you could do is have your own class (`FooNumbers` or such), write only the instances you want, and then require that instead of `Num`. But that's usually not helpful.

Comment: The caveat at the end, is that warning against the class (Num a) => option?

Comment: @peroni_santo: No, it's about trying to restrict it to only a handful of specific types instead of "anything with a `Num` instance". Both examples I gave in code are fine.